# problema de valor nulo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo enlazada una base de datos y al cargar en un texbox una registro con valor nulo no me permite. solo quiero que al ser un dato nulo deje en blanco el texbox

```
while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        tbId.Text = reader.GetString(0);
                        tbNombre.Text = reader.GetString(1);
                        tbDescripcion.Text = reader.GetString(2);
                        tbCantidad.Text = reader.GetString(3);
                        tbIdGrupo.Text = reader.GetString(4);
                        tbIdMarca.Text = reader.GetString(5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto...

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
   while (reader.Read())
   {
      tbId.Text = reader.GetString(0);
      .....
   }
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("No se encontraron filas.");
}
reader.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Usted puede indicar que si el dato viene nulo entonces lo inicialize como un string vacío de esta forma :

```
while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        tbId.Text = reader.GetString(0)?? string.Empty;
                        tbNombre.Text = reader.GetString(1)?? string.Empty;
                        tbDescripcion.Text = reader.GetString(2)?? string.Empty;
                        tbCantidad.Text = reader.GetString(3)?? string.Empty;
                        tbIdGrupo.Text = reader.GetString(4)?? string.Empty;
                        tbIdMarca.Text = reader.GetString(5)?? string.Empty;}
```